# Error when restore wallet from private keys

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, viewkey, privatekey, stagenet

I'm trying to create a wallet from private keys. The keys are checked [here](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html), but when I try to enter them into the monero-wallet-cli , I get a validation error:

```
./monero-wallet-cli --stagenet --generate-from-keys mywallet.abc
This is the command line monero wallet. It needs to connect to a monero
daemon to work correctly.
WARNING: Do not reuse your Monero keys on another fork, UNLESS this fork has key reuse mitigations built in. Doing so will harm your privacy.

Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.3.0-release)
Logging to ./monero-wallet-cli.log
Standard address: 58v4zJf4QzxVVyF2kbFRUygNHGCMkzCYiBbwyPa1rbFaaojc4rTi78yMJbWRAgNdj2BSmgijiCixcZN3pEiyXkcoRnPbZ5C
Secret spend key: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

Secret view key: a15a2245c51fcb50f2bad06a05af68926e4a730efc0cc8b42e9e06a430a84178

Error: failed to verify spend key secret key
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you followed [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/restoring-wallet-from-keys-file/10721#10721)? It's important to enter the correct public keys when prompted. Also see [this](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/generating-wallet-from-private-key).

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. It seems that private keys must be less than "[Prime order of the base point](https://monerodocs.org/cryptography/asymmetric/edwards25519/#prime-order-of-the-base-point-l)"

```
l = 2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493
# => 7237005577332262213973186563042994240857116359379907606001950938285454250989
```

Comment: So you used a key file not obtained from the official wallets?

Comment: Yes. Yes, I'm trying to make my own library for working with keys

Comment: In that case, you have to reduce mod `l` to be a valid private key.